# label the lines that have and do not have result in the next line

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, awk, command-line

I have a list like this:

```
#chrom  start   end seq
#chrom  start   end seq
#chrom  start   end seq
chr1    214435102   214435132   AAACCGGTCAGCTT...
chr1    214435135   214435165   TCAATGGACTGTTC...
#chrom  start   end seq 
chr1    214873901   214873931   CCAAATCCCTCAGG...
```

As it is seen some of them have results (3rd and 4th) and some of them do not (1st and 2nd)

What I am trying to do is first read the line that starts with '*#chrom*' and read the line after that line. If the next line also starts with '*#chrom*' print 0, if it starts with something else print 1. And do it for every line that starts with '*#chrom*' **without** passing any.
I am kind of trying to label the ones that have sequences. I am guessing that there would be an easier way of doing it but what I could create up until now is two lines of code;

```
awk '/#chrom/{getline; print}' raw.txt > nextLine.txt
awk '$1 == "#chrom" { print "0" } $1 != "#chrom" { print "1" }' nextLine.txt > labeled.txt
```

Expected output in the labeled.txt;

```
0
0
1
1
```

I guess the second line of the code works well. However, the line counts that include '*#chrom*' in the raw.txt and nextLine.txt are not matching. If you could help me with that I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please add the expected output for your input? It is not clear to me what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, sure I added it. Sorry

Comment: do all lines start with `#chrom` or `chr`? or can lines start with other strings of characters? can lines be blank? will the first line in file always be a `#chrom` and if not, how should that line be treated (perhaps update the question to show such a line in your input along with an update of the expected output)

Comment: @markp-fuso all lines start either with #chrom or chr. the file can not start with chr it is known that it starts with #chrom 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in life, in software its much easier to do things based on what HAS happened than on what WILL happen. So don't write requirements based on what the NEXT line of input will be, write them based on what the PREVIOUS line of input was and you'll find it much easier to figure out the matching code and that code will be simpler than trying to determine the next line of input.

```
$ cat tst.awk
($1 == "#chrom") && (NR > 1) {
    print ( prev == "#chrom" ? 0 : 1 )
}
{ prev = $1 }
END {
    print ( prev == "#chrom" ? 0 : 1 )
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
0
0
1
1
```

Comment: that's also something I am trying to fix in my real-life perspective :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN { chrom=0 } { 
   if ($1=="#chrom") { 
      if (chrom==1) print 0; else chrom=1; } 
   else { 
      if (chrom==1) print 1; chrom=0 } 
   }'
```

Comment: You don't even need the `BEGIN` block +1

Comment: @Fravadona my bad habit !

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
{ if (prev=="#chrom")                 # for 1st line of input prev==""
     print ($1 == "#chrom" ? 0 : 1)   # use ternary operator to determine output
  prev=$1
}
' raw.txt
```

or as a one-liner:

```
awk '{if (prev=="#chrom") print ($1 == "#chrom" ? 0 : 1); prev=$1}' raw.txt
```

This generates:

```
0
0
1
1
```

Comment: That would print nothing for the final line if it started with `#chrom`

Comment: depends on the next to last line; if next to last line is `#chrom` then a last line of `#chrom` will genrate a `0`; if next to last line is `chr*` then there's nothing to print since output is determined based on the *previous* line containing `#chrom`; if OP wants something output based on `chr* \n #chrom` then that's a special case which OP has not (yet) defined

Comment: Yes this does not give a result for the last line if it does not have a result. Sorry if I could not explain my question clearly, what is OP exactly? thank you.